# Connect to Oracle DB using sqlplus

Tags: oracle, unix, sqlplus

I am using below command in Unix environment to connect to Oracle database:

```
sqlplus test/test@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname.com )(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mysid))'
```

But I am getting below error:

```
Use SQL*Plus to execute SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*Plus statements.

Usage 1: sqlplus -H | -V

    -H             Displays the SQL*Plus version and the
                   usage help.
    -V             Displays the SQL*Plus version.

Usage 2: sqlplus [ [<option>] [{logon | /nolog}] [<start>] ]

  <option> is: [-C <version>] [-L] [-M "<options>"] [-R <level>] [-S]
```

Please help me where I am doing mistake in using the command.

Comment: Are your parentheses balanced?

Comment: Yes that is the issue, I missed 1 closing bracket in the command. Thanks a lot David.

Comment: If your client is configured to allow EZCONNECT for Oracle name resolution, you can use sqlplus test/test@hostname.com:1521/mysid instead - much easier IMHO.

Answer (score 10):

try this: 
`sqlplus USER/PW@//hostname:1521/SID`

Comment: For the port, you should check `oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora`, sometimes it is 1522 if you have installed another Oracle before.

Comment: I have 1526 on of of the bases, and yeah, it can be different. Pretty obvious for me.

Answer (score 4):

> sqlplus username/password@database

Eg:

> sqlplus hr/hr@orcl

Answer (score 4):

Different ways to connect Oracle Database from Unix user are:

```
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger@192.168.244.128:1521/orcl

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger@//192.168.244.128:1521/orcl

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus "scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))"
```

Please see the explanation at link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45064809/6332029

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easy way (using XE):

1). Configure your tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HOST.DOMAIN.COM)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

You can replace HOST.DOMAIN.COM with IP address, the TCP port by default is 1521 (ckeck it) and look that name of this configuration is XE

2). Using your app named sqlplus:

```
sqlplus SYSTEM@XE
```

SYSTEM should be replaced with an authorized USER, and put your password when prompt appear

3). See at firewall for any possibilities of some blocked TCP ports and fix it if appear

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect with oracle database

1. open sql prompt
2. connect with sysdba
   for XE- conn / as sysdba
   for IE- conn sys as sysdba
3. then start up database by below command
   startup;

once it get start means you can access oracle database now.
if you want connect another user you can write  conn username/password 
e.g. conn scott/tiger;
it will show connected........

Comment: Please don't include links to unrelated websites in your answers - it looks like spam.

Answer (score 0):

```
tnsping xe --if you have installed express edition
tnsping orcl --or if you have installed enterprise or standard edition then try to run
--if you get a response with your description then you will write the below command
sqlplus  --this will prompt for user
hr --user that you have created or use system
password --inputted at the time of user creation for hr, or put the password given at the time of setup for system user
hope this will connect if db run at your localhost.
--if db host in a remote host then you must use tns name for our example orcl or xe
try this to connect remote
hr/pass...@orcl or hr/pass...@xe --based on what edition you have installed
```

Answer (score 0):

As David Aldridge explained, your parentheses should start right after the sqlplus command, so it should be:

`sqlplus 'test/test@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname.com )(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mysid))'`

Answer (score 0):

it would be something like this

```
sqlplus -s /nolog  <<-!
connect ${ORACLE_UID}/${ORACLE_PWD}@${ORACLE_DB};
whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set pagesize 0;
set linesize 150;
spool <query_output.dat> APPEND
@$<input_query.dat>
spool off;
exit;
!
```

here

```
ORACLE_UID=<user name>
ORACLE_PWD=<password>
ORACLE_DB=//<host>:<port>/<DB name>
```