# how to connect to an oracle database from unix

Tags: database, oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus

I am trying to connect to an oracle database from my unix machine. I am new to script writing in general. I know how to browse round unix and have written basic scripts ( read / display ) and execute them with bash command. Also I know how to view the variables in unix ( user and system). Could you tell me what i need to do to connect to an oracle database? do I use the sqlplus command? are there any variables I have to set before that?

Comment: sqlplus is the easiest way, you'll want to make sure $ORACLE_HOME is set - the rest of the answer will depend on how you want to connect. And no matter what, you'll need the connection information - do you know where the database is, what port the listener is on, the name of the db/service,  and have a username/password?

Comment: Sure I know the host / database schema / user ID and password. Also I think I need to setup the environment variables as indicated by the other users here in this thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could you tell me what i need to do to connect to an oracle database? do I use the sqlplus command?

Well, yes of course, you need to use SQL*Plus. However, before that, you need to make sure of few things:

1. export ORACLE_HOME variable

For example,

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0
```

2. export PATH variable

For example,

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

3. export SID

For example,

```
export ORACLE_SID="your database service name"
```

4. Make sure you have the `tnsnames.ora` configured properly
5. Make sure you have the `listener` up and running and is listening to the correct port.

You should be able to connect to the database as:

```
sqlplus username/password@sid
```

Comment: So oracle would have to be installed on the Unix server ? ( for export ORACLE_HOME )?

Comment: You need to tell us whether you are connecting to a local DB server or remotely? I am assuming you have installed Oracle in the Unix machine you are currently logged in.

Comment: I will be connecting remotely , also how do I check if I have oracle installed on the Unix machine ?

Comment: Just do `which oracle`

Comment: /> which oracle
no oracle in /usr/bin .

Comment: So you need to first install oracle in your unix box. Anyway, please mark it as answered. It will help others.

Comment: do you suggest this documentation for installation? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ape.htm

Comment: That link is only to install the client. You need to first doenload the database software, unzip it and then run the installer. Google for install oracle on unix and there are millions of articles with screenshots step by step installation guide. Good luck!

Comment: do I have to install the full software eben though I will be connecting to a remote database?

Comment: You can also install Oracle SQL Developer - only requirement is a JDK and that you have your library path set correctly.

Comment: Download the required instant client as per your OS, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Comment: For existing DB that is already setup properly, to connect to remote oracle DB from linux using sqlplus: `sqlplus <username>/<password>@<alias_set_in_tnsnames.ora>`. For example if entry in your tnsnames.ora is `alias_nm=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =host-nm.something.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =      
      (SERVICE_NAME =service_nm.something.com)
    )
  )`
Then you should use: `sqlplus <username>/<password>@alias_nm`

Comment: @LalitKumarB Can you please provide examples of `ORACLE_SID "your database service name"`?

Answer (score 1):

Set ORACLE_HOME & ORACLE_SID environment variable.
Then use 
sqlplus username@ORACLE_SID

Comment: Thanks let me set that

Comment: just found out that i have to install oracle on my machine

Comment: Yes, you need to install oracle on your machine. If you wan't to use remote database , you need to set up remote database entry in your tnsnames.ora file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've exported all the necessary Oracle variable in your unix user path environment as below:

```
ORACLE_BASE=/home/oracle/app; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=orcl; export ORACLE_SID
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
```

And Make sure tnsnames.ora file is configured properly and listener should be up and running as below.

```
[oracle@OLE1 admin]$ cat tnsnames.ora 
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ole1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ tnsping orcl
TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 12-JUL-2017 23:12:35
Copyright (c) 1997, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ole1)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))
OK (20 msec)
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ 

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost
192.168.244.128 ole1
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$
```

Now you've multiple ways to connect database from unix command prompt.

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger@192.168.244.128:1521/orcl

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger@//192.168.244.128:1521/orcl

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus "scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))"

```
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jul 12 23:29:30 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jul 12 23:30:00 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ 

[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger@192.168.244.128:1521/orcl
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jul 12 23:30:00 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ 


[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus scott/tiger@//192.168.244.128:1521/orcl
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Jul 12 23:30:00 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$ sqlplus "scott/tiger@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ole1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))"

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Jul 13 12:30:23 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> 
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
[oracle@OLE1 ~]$
```