# SQL Plus: How do I specify a database or instance to connect to when multiple instances are installed

Tags: oracle

On Windows Server 2012 R2, I have Oracle 11G and Oracle 12C installed.
Everyting is working as needed, I am able to use SQL Developer to connect to individual instances.

However, in addition to using SQL Developer, I need to use SQL Plus. 
How do I specify which Instance to connect to using commands?

In the TNS file, each instance is on a separate port and has a different SID but uses the same IP.

Thanks

Comment: I think this [answer on the Database Administrartors section](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65032/connect-to-sql-plus-from-command-line-using-connection-string) of SO answers your question..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to Oracle DB using sqlplus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661076/connect-to-oracle-db-using-sqlplus)

Answer (score 0):

you can always
 connect user/password@server:port/SID|SERVICE